Enumerate in Beamer
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{savedenum}
\newcommand*{\saveenum}{\setcounter{savedenum}{\theenumi}}
\newcommand*{\resume}{\setcounter{enumi}{\thesavedenum}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \saveenum
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \resume
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

This works well in resuming the enumeration but I cannot manage to change the enumeration to letters. I have tried using \alph{} but I have not been able to sort it out.

I just figured it out :) Apologies.

After trying again, I was able to do the following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{savedenum}
\newcommand*{\saveenum}{\setcounter{savedenum}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand*{\resume}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{savedenum}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \item First item
    \item Second item
    \saveenum
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}[a)]
    \resume
    \item Third item
    \item Fourth item
  \end{enumerate}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


